# Getting a more accurate CGRectContainsPoint result

Tags: iphone

I'm new to posting on this forum but can't tell you how many times reading it has helped me out. Currently I'm working on a game for the iPhone it has a grid of UIImageViews that are contained within a subview of my gameboardViewController. I build the grid on ViewDidLoad. Ok so far. Now I am using touchesBegan to figure out which one of the UIImageViews was touched, which kind-of works. I say kind-of because CGRectContainsPoint seems to give a false result, meaning the top row of this grid is thought by that function to be outside of my subview rect.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.gridView];

    CGRect gridRect = self.gridView.frame;
    // Since I have an overlay I want to ignore touches when this subview is visible.
    if(self.readyScreen.hidden)
    {
        /* restrict the touches to only the subview gridView so any stray touches should be ignored.*/
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(gridRect,currentLocation) )
        {
            UIImageView *theTile = (UIImageView *)touch.view;
            [self gridItemTouched:theTile];
        }
    }
```

}

For some reason it isn't accurate enough to see that the top row of 50 x 50 UIImageViews are within the subview.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You convert the tap location to the `gridView`’s coordinate system. But then you check if this coodinate it is contained in the `gridView`’s frame, which is in its superviews coordinate system.

You have two choices to fix this:

Either use `gridView`’s coodinate system:

```
CGPoint currentLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.gridView.superview];
```

Or use the superview’s coodinate system:

```
CGRect gridRect = self.gridView.bounds;
```

Comment: Ah I see thanks for the help. I now have it working as expected. Stay tuned for my next question as I'm sure I'll have more.